# create datatable from laravel excel array

Tags: php, jquery, excel, laravel, datatables

i need to upload excel file and create datatable from array. How to do that? I have problem with making postExcel return.

im using http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs and
http://datatables.net/

Here is my code:

```
public function postExcel(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()) {

        if ($request->hasFile('file'))
        {
            $file = $request->file('file');
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

            //$file->getRealPath();
            $path = $file->move(public_path(), $filename);

            \Excel::load($path, function($reader){

                $results = $reader->toArray();

            });
            print_r($results);die();
            $json = array(
                'status' => 'ok',
                'array' => $results
            );
        }
        return Response::json($json);
    }
}
```

and this is views js there i need generate table:

```
$(document).on("change", "#file-input", function() {
    var formData = new FormData($('form.upload-excel')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        url: '/Excel/public/upload-excel',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data.status === 'ok') {
                console.log(data.array);
                $('#table').DataTable({
                    colReorder: true,
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What does your data look like that is returned from `ajax`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. it was:

```
            $data = \Excel::load($path)->toArray();

            $json = array(
                'status' => 'ok',
                'data' => $data
            );
```